# Show image on picture box when clicking on datagridview row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm in need of some piece of code to help me out to print a Image that is stored on a datagrid row or SQL DB image, and i wanted to do something useful out of it.

My point is to insert a image everytime i click on a datarow.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Trabalhos\AuthMyRegistery\AuthMyRegistery\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    id_Worker_Info = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id_Worker_Info"].Value.ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Worker where id_Worker_Info='" +id_Worker_Info+ "';";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
       WorkerIdTextBox.Text = dr["id_Worker_Info"].ToString();
       NameTextBox.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
       FnameTextBox.Text = dr["Formation_Name"].ToString();
       BirthTextBox.Text = dr["Date_of_Birth"].ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data come in from a byte array, e.g. a blob type that contains valid image data this should work:

```
    using System.IO;
    ..

    byte[] iData = (byte[])dr[yourColumnIndexOrName];
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (iData != null)
       using (var ms = new MemoryStream(iData ))
       {
           bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
       } 
    pb_image.Image = bmp;  // display in a PictureBox
```

It is up to you to decide on the `SizeMode` and the `Size` of the `PictureBox`. You can test the `bmp.Size`, if you want to..

Don't forget to clean up the bitmap before assigning a new one:

```
if (pb_image.Image != null)
{
    Image img = pb_image.Image;
    pb_image.Image = null;
    img.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I really apreciate it, i really do! :)